# OpenMP how to keep array in cache

Tags: arrays, openmp, cpu-cache

I sequentially generate a number which then is looked up in an array which never change. Therefore it would be convenient if this array some how stays in the spawned threads cache.

```
unsigned int unordered_set[65535];
void init_set( unsigned int *a) {
...
}

unsigned int generate_number() {
...
}

unsigned int find_number(unsigned int a) {
    unsigned int result=0;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<65535;i++) {
        if (unordered_set[i]==a)
            result=i;
    }
    return result
}

void main() {
    unsigned int x;
    /* Fill the array with unique numbers */
    init_set(unordered_set);
    while(x>0) {
        /*This loop can only be done sequentially */
        x=generate_number();
        unsigned int r=find_number(x);
        if (r>0)
            printf ("Found: %d %d",x,r);
    }
}
```

I suppose that this never happens in the above code. Every time find_number is called the array unordered_set again and again is loaded into the threads caches. What can be done to ensure that the array stays in cache?

Comment: "I suppose that this never happens" What leads to you believe that?

Comment: In order to provide an accurate statement of what is going on on your system, you should profile (e.g. `perf record` and then `perf report`) your application, activating the cache-references and cache-misses events to prove that the problem is taking place.

Comment: In addition, regular processors would not have much trouble on keeping the arrays on the cache for such an small program. Your whole array will not fit in a single L1-D cache (typically 32kB or 64kB) but in the higher levels. After the first iterations of the loop, each thread in the parallel for will get their corresponding part.

Comment: You should read about false sharing, you have a nice example there

Comment: I thought that for the scheduler at the very next iteration of x, it would be to difficult to figure out which core already has the code and data needed to ensure full parallelity, but I am delighted if you think that this is not a problem.
About false sharing. I assume you think about result=i, but that instruction is only executed once by a single thread since unordered_set never contains the same number twice.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Actually I thought you're writing to the array, `result` would be real sharing, not false, but it's fine like you say. There is some wastefulness in how you distribute the work - since each thread will read a single int, but will need to cache an entire cache line. I would unroll the loop so that each thread will check 64B or 128B worth of sequential elements (aligned), so that each core will consume full cachelines without wasting cache on adjacent ones. Also, doing more work per core will  reduce the heavy overhead of having to read `x` (currently each thread will miss it)